# smooth functional to detect whether a function has a zero

Tags: real-analysis, smoothness, zeroes

Does there exist a function $F : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}, [0, \infty)) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

- $F(f) = 0$ if and only if there exists an $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.
- $F$ is *smooth* in the following sense:  if $f(x,t) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, [0,\infty))$ and $F$ is applied to $f$ in the $x$ variable, the function of $t$ that results is smooth ($C^\infty$).

The second question is whether the following candidate satisfies the smoothness property.  For $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}, [0, \infty))$, define $G(f)$ to be
$$
    \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx \right)^{-2}
$$
if $f$ has no zeros in $[0,1]$, and $0$ otherwise.
Then $G$ satisfies the first condition by definition,
and one can show that when $f$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ as above, $G(f)$ is (continuous and) differentiable as a function of $t$.  Is it smooth?

**Edit:** Willie Wong answered the second question in the negative.  So let's instead define $G(f)$ to be
$$
    \exp \left( -\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx \right)
$$
if $f$ has no zeros in $[0,1]$, and $0$ otherwise.
Is this $G$ smooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A functional that works is
$$
  F(f)=\begin{cases} \exp(-\exp(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)}dx)), & \textrm{if $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$} \\
                     0,                                      & \textrm{otherwise}.
       \end{cases}
$$
The idea to use this formula and a sketch of the proof that it works are both due to Chengjie Yu.  The proof is in the appendix of a paper I wrote with Enxin Wu, Smooth classifying spaces, http://arxiv.org/abs/1709.10517

I don't know whether the functional described in the question, $G(f) = \exp(-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} dx)$, works.

Answer (score 5):

For the **second question** only:

For $f(x,t) = (x-t)^2$, you have that if $t > 1$

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x,t)} ~dx =  \frac{1}{t-x} \Big|^1_0 = \frac{1}{t - 1} - \frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{t(t-1)} $$

So you functional 
$$ G(f)(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & t \leq 1 \\
t^2(t-1)^2 & t > 1\end{cases} $$

and is not a smooth function of $t$ (not even $C^2$).

---

This example can of course be circumvented if you take instead of $(\int_0^1 \cdot dx)^{-2}$ something like $\exp - (\int_0^1 \cdot dx)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!  I've updated the question to take your answer into account.  I'd really like to know the answer to the first question!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the proof that either of the definitions of $G$ in the question satisfy a weaker version of the smoothness condition.  I hope that the same ideas can be used to prove that the second definition is in fact smooth.  So we'll discuss that case.

Define $G(f)$ to be $\exp(-\int_0^1 dx/f(x))$ if $f$ is non-zero on $[0,1]$, and let $G(f) = 0$ otherwise.  Let $f(x,t) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, [0, \infty))$.  We'll show that the first derivative of $G(f)$ with respect to $t$ exists for all $t$.  Without loss of generality, we'll do this at $t=0$.  If $f(x,0)$ is nonzero on $[0,1]$, then this is also true for $t$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, and $G(f)$ is smooth in this neighbourhood by differentiating under the integral.

If $f(x,0)$ has a zero in $[0,1]$, then $G(f)$ is zero when $t=0$, and we'll show below that there exists $c > 0$ such that
$$
  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x,t)} dx \geq \frac{c}{|t|} \tag{*}
$$
for all $t \in [-1,1]$ such that $f(x,t)$ is nonzero for all $x \in [0,1]$.  Therefore,
$$
  \exp \left( -\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x,t)} dx \right) \leq \exp \left( -\frac{c}{|t|} \right)
$$
for such $t$.
Therefore,
$$
  G(f) \leq \exp \left( -\frac{c}{|t|} \right)
$$
for *all* nonzero $t \in [-1,1]$, since either $G(f) = 0$, or $G(f)$ is as in the previous equation.
It follows that the first derivative of $G(f)$ exists and is zero at $t = 0$.

**Can the argument be adapted to handle the higher derivatives?**

---

Proof of the inequality (*):

Let $x_0 \in [0,1]$ be such that $f(x_0,0) = 0$. Then, by smoothness, there exists $C > 0$ such that 
$$
  f(x,t) \leq C (t^2 + (x - x_0)^2)
$$
for every $t \in [-1,1]$ and $x \in [0,1]$. The squares comes from the fact that $f$ is assumed to be a non-negative smooth function, so $\partial_x f(x_0,0) =  \partial_t f(x_0,0) = 0$.
In particular, if $|x - x_0| \leq |t| \leq 1$, then
$$
  f(x,t) \leq 2 C t^2 .
$$
Choose $t \in [-1,1]$ such that $f(x,t)$ has no zeros for $x \in [0,1]$.
Integrating, we get
$$
  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x,t)} dx
  \geq \int_{\max(x_0 - |t|,0)}^{\min(x_0 + |t|,1)} \frac{1}{f(x,t)} dx
  \geq \int_{\max(x_0 - |t|,0)}^{\min(x_0 + |t|,1)} \frac{1}{2 C t^2} dx
  \geq \frac{|t|}{2 C t^2} = \frac{c}{|t|},
$$
as claimed.  The last inequality comes from the fact that the interval of integration has width at least $|t|$.

That $f$ is non-negative is crucial here: the argument given above does not work if $f$ can be real valued, and this can be seen explicitly for the example $f(x,t) = x-t$. However, in such a situation one could simply replace the integrand $1/f$ with $1 / f^2$.

Comment: The inequality ($*$) makes no sense at $t=0$, so how can it hold for all $t \in [-1,1]$?  Also I do not understand the assumptions on $f$ in the sentence *If $f(x,0)$ has a zero in $[0,1]$, then ... one can show that ...  such that $f(x,t)$ is nonzero for $x \in [0,1]$*.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thanks for pointing out the typo about the case where $t$ might be zero.  I've added "nonzero" to that sentence.  Regarding your second question, for each fixed $t$, either $f(x,t)$ has a zero for some $x \in [0,1]$, or it doesn't.  Which of those is true determines which formula is used to define $G(f)$ for that $t$.

Comment: I still don't understand that sentence.  What if the support of f is in [1/4,3/4] then there are a continuum of zeros.  How is your taylor series argument valid?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: I am not entirely sure I understand your objection, in part because $f$ depends on two variables and your last comment only talks about support in [1/4,3/4]. Is that in relation to $x$ or to $t$?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: I edited the answer and filled in the proof.

Comment: @WillieWong sorry for the delay: I had to teach.  It was in relation to $x$, but it looks like your argument fills in the details.  I was concerned that the Taylor series argument may have assumed that $f(\cdot,t)$ had a discrete number of zeros.  For the purpose of detecting a zero of $f$, its clear that one can take $f$ to be non-negative WLOG.

Comment: BTW, I don't see how this functional is practical as a means to detect a zero of f, because its evaluation seems to rely on another routine to detect this zero.  So I don't see how this functional answers the OPs question.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: since the answerer is the OP, I can only assume he knows how it answered the question. :-)

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for filling in the proof of (*).  It's essentially the same as my proof, although I didn't need to treat interior points of $g^{-1}(0)$ specially.  However, Gord Sinnamon pointed out an error in the last sentence of the argument I gave above;  it only handles the first derivative, giving the same result I had already proved for $(\int 1/f)^{-2}$.  Any ideas for how to handle higher derivatives?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I don't intend to find zeros by practically computing this functional.  The use would be to find a local trivialization of a principle $G$-bundle with an associated smooth partition of unity, following Dold's argument in the topological case, which uses the function $g$ that arose in Willie Wong's proof of (*).

Comment: @WillieWong If $t=0$ is in the boundary of the closed set $g^{-1}(0)$, I don't see why there is an interval $(0,t_0)$ on which $g(t) > 0$.  Instead, I would drop the discussion of $g$ completely.  All of the inequalities should still hold for each $t$ such that $f(x,t)$ has no zeros for $x \in [0,1]$.  And for $t$ such that $f(x,t)$ does have such a zero, $G(f) = 0$, so there is nothing to prove.  I think this fixes the mistake and simplifies the argument at the same time.  If you agree with this reasoning, I'm happy to make the changes.

Comment: @DanChristensen: you are right. The discussion of $g$ was a vestigial paragraph from an earlier version of a "proof" that didn't quite work, I just failed to completely erase its presence. Sorry about that! You can go ahead and edit: after all, I _am_ the interloper and it is your answer :-)